# Sending Email with Java script through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a long piece of Java script code and I need to add Email action in the middle of the code. However, I know that I cannot directly send Email with Java script so I used :

```
           $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"mail.php",
            success:function(){
            alert("it was a success");
             }
           });
             window.location = url;
           }

          });
```

inside of my mail.php file I have very simple Email tag which is :

```
   <?php

  //send email
   mail('test@gmial.com','My Subject' , 'test');

  ?>
```

However it says "it was success" on JS but it does not do anything on PHP. I even tried to print something on PHP but it does not work. Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you setup an mail server on your server?

Try this:

```
if( !mail('test@gmial.com','My Subject' , 'test') )
   echo "Probably no mail server found.";
else
   echo "mail server is not the problem."
```

And log it in js:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"mail.php",
            success:function(res){
            console.log(res);
             }
           });
             window.location = url;
           }

          });
```

Comment: Yes I already set up Email configuration.

Comment: I guess it does not redirect to mail.php because it did not print anything.

Comment: what is with you console...did you get any js errors?

Comment: I also removed url:"mail.php" again it says it was a success

Comment: Obviously it does not redirect to mail.php. What is the problem here?:(

Comment: then, wrong directory (for example "php/mail.php" or permission problems.

Comment: I put them in same directory. I will also check the permission.